# Htaccess 404 issue with homepage

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

My htaccess 404 rule is set as follows:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.htm
```

but this is what happens:

Non-existent url with no extension:
https://www.example.com/bgbgbgbgbg redirects to https://www.example.com/404.htm (**correct behaviour**)

non-existent url with a dot:
https://www.example.com/bgbgbgbgbg. redirects to https://www.example.com/404.htm (**correct behaviour**)

non-existent url with extension:
https://www.example.com/bgbgbgbgbg.htm redirects to "file not found" (**should redirect to** https://www.example.com/404.htm)

url endng with a slash:
https://www.example.com/bgbgbgbgbg/ redirects to a weird 404 page with no css, and the urls in the browser's address bar does not change (**should redirect to** https://www.example.com/404.htm)

I did some research and tred implementing these lines right under ErrorDocument 404 /404.htm:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . https://www.example.com/404.htm [L]
```

it solves everything, BUT it redirects the homepage (https://www.example.com) to https://www.example.com/404.htm

What can I do in order to solve the homepage issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect non existent requests to 404 error page you can simply use  :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.+$ /404.htm [L,R]
```